# Writing each column of each row of the table into a new cell in a csv file using python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server-2012, export-to-csv

I am new to Python and I am trying to write each column of each row of the table into a new cell in .csv file using python 3. My current code writes it all to a single column but different rows.

Here is the code:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("Select * from ITSDatabaseDetails")

with open(csvfile, 'w', newline='') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=';', quotechar=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])  # heading row
    writer.writerows(cur.fetchall())
```

I tried to loop the result like follows but did not work (I replaced last 2 lines of the above code with the code below). I ended up with a blank .csv file:

```
for row in cur:
    for column in row:
        writer.writerow(column)
```

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the delimiter parameter to ',' in my original code resolved the issue.

```
 writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```